# Populate a text box with todays date but don't want that date to be posted when I search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, date

I have successfully populated two date search fields with today's date using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
}
```

I wish to search a gridview using any two dates.  The problem is that it only shows results from today's date and not from between the dates I have selected.

My select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM News 
WHERE (([articleDate] >= @articleDate) AND ([articleDate] <= @articleDate2))
```

I'm guessing it is something to do with the Page_Load event, but don't know where to start.

Comment: What are the values of those two variables?  If you run the query with those dates outside your application, do you get the same results you are seeing inside your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page-load loads those two variables in the textboxes the things you write in the textbox will never get used.

Try to surround the code in the pageload with:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    If(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    }

}
```